# Spring security not blocking all requests

Tags: spring, spring-security

I'm using Spring security 3.2 and have this configuration:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {      
    http
            .headers()
                .addHeaderWriter(new XFrameOptionsHeaderWriter(XFrameOptionsMode.SAMEORIGIN))
                .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint)
                .and()
            .rememberMe()
                .rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices())
                .key(env.getProperty("security.rememberme.key"))
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl("/app/authentication")
                .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
                .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
                .usernameParameter("j_username")
                .passwordParameter("j_password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl("/app/logout")
                .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .addFilter(basicAuthenticationFilter(basicAuthenticationEntryPoint(), authenticationManager()))
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/login/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/logout/**").permitAll()                
                .antMatchers("/super_admin/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/administration/**").hasRole("ADMIN")
                .antMatchers("/*").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/app/**").authenticated();
```

When I'm logged as user with role ADMIN and I'm accessing `http://mydomain:8080/super_admin` and `http://mydomain:8080/#/administration` this is not being blocked. (Works fine)

But when I log in as user without role ADMIN this is being blocked `http://mydomain:8080/super_admin`, but I can still access `http://mydomain:8080/#/administration`.
Is there a problem with #? 
How I can block `http://mydomain:8080/#/administration`

Thank you for any feedback.

Answer (score 1):

Values after the `#` are not send to the server.  You have to use some JavaScript to check if it's ok for the user to access the page.

Answer (score 0):

Evgeni is correct, the values after the # is called the fragment or anchor part of the URL, and is used by web browsers not the server.

Example of a fragment URL http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurricane_Ginger#Impact. This link will take you to Hurricane_Ginger heading Impact